# Doctest of function to make a list of squares

Tags: python, doctest

I am trying to define a function to return squares for integers within a given range:

```
#this is my code

def squares(start, end):
    """
    Given the starting and ending numbers,
    return a list of the squares of the numbers from start to end.

    >>>squares(1, 5)
    [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
    >>>squares(2, 4)
    [4, 9, 16]
    >>>squares(0, 1)
    [0, 1]
    >>>squares(0, 2)
    [0, 1, 4]
    """
    return [i**2 for i in range(start, end+1)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True, optionflags=doctest.NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE)
```

This is causing about 30 other errors and I dont know how to fix it.

```
    ValueError: line 5 of the docstring for __main__.squares lacks blank after >>>: '>>>squares(1, 5)'
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Fixing the error

Just add some spaces:

```
def squares(start, end):
    """
    Given the starting and ending numbers,
    return a list of the squares of the numbers from start to end.

    >>> squares(1, 5)
    [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
    >>> squares(2, 4)
    [4, 9, 16]
    >>> squares(0, 1)
    [0, 1]
    >>> squares(0, 2)
    [0, 1, 4]
    """
    return [i**2 for i in range(start, end+1)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True, optionflags=doctest.NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE)
```

#### How to read a python stacktrace

Reading a python stacktrace can be tricky.  First, note that it did not generate "about 30 other errors."  Python stops at the first error.  In this case, the error is:

```
ValueError: line 5 of the docstring for __main__.squares lacks blank after >>>: '>>>squares(1, 5)'
```

It tells you to add a space between `>>>` and the command `squares(1, 5)`.

The rest of the confusing lines tell the path that python took to get to that error.  Lets look at the first few lines:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sq.py", line 20, in <module>
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True, optionflags=doctest.NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1885, in testmod
    for test in finder.find(m, name, globs=globs, extraglobs=extraglobs):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 900, in find
    self._find(tests, obj, name, module, source_lines, globs, {})
```

These lines are not separate errors.  They tell how python reached the line that gave the error.  For starters, it says that python was executing line 20 of your file `sq.py` which called `doctest.testmod`.  From there, it went to line 1885 of `doctest.py` which called line 900 of  `doctest.py` and so on.